# Datepicker modal popup not working properly - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Jquery datepicker modal popup not working properly!!

If i select current date from Greaterthan date, i want to show popup like "This is future date"
and if i select less than current date, i want to show popup like "This is past date"
and even i select current date, same i want to show popup line "This is Todays date"

> Example: if i click **< current date** (Show popup **This is past
>   date**), 
>   **> current date** (Show popup **This is future date**),
>   **equal to Current date** (Show popup **This is Todays date**).

Im using this function but its not working properly..

i hope my question is understandable..

Here is my fiddle..

**[FIDDLE HERE..](https://jsfiddle.net/joelshah/k5r2t6eg/)**

Here is my snippet..

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker().on("change", function(e) {
    var today = new Date();
    var date = (today.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + (today.getDate()) + "/" + (today.getFullYear());
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    if ($(this).val() == date) {
      $(".modal-body p").html("You have selected today");
    } else if ($(this).val() < date) {
      $(".modal-body p").html("You have selected past date");
    } else {
      $(".modal-body p").html("You have selected future date");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!Doctype>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.5/datepicker.css" integrity="sha256-n3ci71vDbbK59GUg1tuo+c3KO7+pnBOzt7BDmOe87s4=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.5/datepicker.js" integrity="sha256-KgOC04qt96w+EFba7KuNt9sT+ahJua25I0I2rrkZHFo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <input type="text" id="datepicker">
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Thank you..

Comment: `its not working properly` - why not?  What happens?  Do you see errors?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Date.parse() which is a built in js function for comparing different date because this will convert given date in milliseconds which will help you to compare date.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker().on("change", function(e) {
    var today = new Date();
    var date = (today.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + (today.getDate()) + "/" + (today.getFullYear());
   date = Date.parse(date);
   var selected_date = Date.parse($(this).val());
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    if (selected_date  == date) {
      $(".modal-body p").html("You have selected today");
    } else if (selected_date < date) {
      $(".modal-body p").html("You have selected past date");
    } else {
      $(".modal-body p").html("You have selected future date");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!Doctype>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.5/datepicker.css" integrity="sha256-n3ci71vDbbK59GUg1tuo+c3KO7+pnBOzt7BDmOe87s4=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.5/datepicker.js" integrity="sha256-KgOC04qt96w+EFba7KuNt9sT+ahJua25I0I2rrkZHFo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <input type="text" id="datepicker">
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Its working only first time for me bro.. after refreshing the page same issues comes arround.. but you code working fine for jsfiddle, codepen and all.. its not work for me only!! Now Past date is working fine but the Future date only the problem for me..

Answer (score 0):

Variable date was not initialising correctly. You should add 0 padding to today.getDate() if number is single digit.

replace date variable initialisation with below line.

```
var date = (today.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + (("0" + today.getDate()).slice(-2)) + "/" + (today.getFullYear());
```